# Progressdialog is not getting dismissed inside the volley response block

Tags: android, progressdialog

My app performs uploading operation to backend php server.My problem is i cannot dismiss the progressdialog inside volley Onresponse() method.Onresponse() method gets executed and toast is displayed in background of the Progressdialog so that means Onresponse() gets called currectly.

I declared ProgressDialog variable in public

**onCreate() method look like this**

```
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.signup);

            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View view) {
                      dialog=new ProgressDialog(context,ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                      dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                      dialog.show(context,"Signing up","Please wait...");
                      login_call();
             }
```

`Login_call()` performs volley request and inside the `onResponse()` i need to dismiss the dialog but its not working.

```
    public void login_call() 
    {
         RequestQueue queue= Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
         StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://192.168.56.1/sign.php", new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            if (response.equals("success")) 
            {

                dialog.dismiss();

                getApplicationContext().startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
            } 
            else 
            {
                dialog.dismiss()
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            dialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }


    ) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> param = new HashMap<>();
            param.put("user",user.getText().toString());
            param.put("pass",pass.getText().toString());
            param.put("name",name.getText().toString());
            param.put("mob",mob.getText().toString());
            param.put("email",email.getText().toString());
           param.put("photo",photo);
            return param;
        }
    };

    queue.add(request);
 }
```

**Toast message is displaying correctly but progressdialog is not gettting dismissed.**

[image]

Any ideas to solve the problem??

Comment: Are you getting _success_ response ?

Comment: Yes iam getting the result that means the toast message gets displayed currectly but that is in background of the progressdialog

Comment: But toast message is in else part and also in error call back. So that means you are not getting _success_ response.

Comment: According to your code, you only display `Toast` message when response is NOT "`success`" -this might explain why the dialog does not get dismissed - because you do not get success. Please add a log statement to show the `response` before the `if-else` block.

Comment: I edited the screenshots its getting currect result and IF statement gets called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change this :

```
RequestQueue queue= Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://192.168.56.1/sign.php", new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {

        dialog.dismiss(); // write it there

        if (response.equals("success")) {

       // dialog.dismiss(); remove this from here..!!


            getApplicationContext().startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)

            );
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
       dialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

> Edit : set this

```
dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
```

Comment: No i also added to dismiss() code to else { } ,but its not working

Comment: remove this `dialog.setIndeterminate(true);`

Comment: make sure you are not calling `dialog.show(context,"Signing up","Please wait...");` at any other place.. i mean **try searching your activity you may be calling it 2 times..!!**

Comment: No dialog.dismiss() without any argument is also not working and i called this method only one time in whole activity.

Comment: My problem got solved by just adding dialog.setIndeterminate(false) Thank you so much

Comment: My pleasure.. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

first in first you didn't check all conditions

```
new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        if (response.equals("success")) {
         dialog.dismiss();
            getApplicationContext().startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
        **} else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }**
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
       dialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

The else block doesn't hide the dialog so you should change it in this way

```
new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        if (response.equals("success")) {
            getApplicationContext().startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
       dialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

I think that the mistake is this, of course assuming that your dialog is accessible from the callback

Comment: No i also added to dismiss() code to else { } ,but its not working

Answer (score 1):

Change your Dialog.show method to use this version: `show(Context context, CharSequence title, CharSequence message, boolean indeterminate, boolean cancelable)` like this:

```
final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Signing up","Please wait...", false, true);
```

So your `onClick` code should change to something like this:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Signing up","Please wait...", false, true); 
    login_call();
     }
```

Please give this a try and let me know if it helps.